# Volume control not working on Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, audio, volume, lxqt

I am on Fedora 38 with LXQt. The volume control has no effect on the volume: if I increase it or decrease it until it is mute, the volume always stays the same. The only way around I have found is to use pavucontrol, which is not straightforward. Moreover, whenever I click on the screen, or pause a video, the volume gets back to its previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sounds like your volume control might not be controlling the volume of the right device.

I don't run LXQt, but [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202834/lxqt-panel-volume-control-doesnt-switch-to-actual-output-device) post by cipricus has an image of what the selection dialog would look like:

[image: Device to Control dialog]

Make sure you've selected "PulseAudio" (or Pipewire, if that's being offered). Pick the same sink you pick in pavucontrol to control the volume.

As answer to the same post, cipricus als recommends using `kmix`. Don't know much KDE that pulls in (which you probably didn't want if you're using LXQt; you might, however, already have most of that, so it's not really a strong argument against; for me, it installs). You can also install `qasmixer`, which however seems not to be aware of pulseaudio at all, and good ole `pasystray`.

That's the command I'd recommend, if the default LXQt volume chooser doesn't work. It's simple, it can just be put into the autostart application list, and it just… works.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You've solved my problem.

Comment: `qasmixer` was a small install for me and worked immediately.